# Ignore some cells for calculation of colum width for an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Browsers calculate an optimal width for columns of a table if there isn't a fixed width. Is there a way to rely on that automatic calculation but ignore the content of some cells?

My use case is the following: I've a table that has a row with filters. Input elements are used for the filters. The input elements should fill up the full width of the column. But they should not affect the width of the column.

This is a simplified version of my table. The columns should have the same width in both versions.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john-doe@examples.com</td>
      <td>203 East 50th St., Suite 1157, New York, NY 10022, USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john-doe@examples.com</td>
      <td>203 East 50th St., Suite 1157, New York, NY 10022, USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john-doe@examples.com</td>
      <td>203 East 50th St., Suite 1157, New York, NY 10022, USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The solution should not use any JavaScript nor a fixed width.

I played around with `position` and `display` style of `<input>` but wasn't able to come up with a solution. But to be honest I'm not an expert in CSS so I might just missed the obvious solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Position:relative`/`absolute` to set input off the document flow , is the only way to avoid input to be taken into account while the table-layout is calculated.

you can set an height to the cells which is actually morelike min-height since , table grows and shrink to fit content .

Demo of what you might have already tested.

```css
table {
 width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
  position:relative;
  height:1.3em;
  
 
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;

}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john-doe@examples.com</td>
      <td>203 East 50th St., Suite 1157, New York, NY 10022, USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>john-doe@examples.com</td>
      <td>203 East 50th St., Suite 1157, New York, NY 10022, USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

other tricky method is to use a negative margin to virtually reduce the room used by the imput to none. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WNNLXKN

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr :first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;/* or min-width or nothing : optionnal */
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: -100vw;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;/* or vertical-align:top; or display:block; or nothing; : to remove gap under input , optionnal */
  /* also , text-indent has no effect on a floatting element */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
      <td><input></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john-doe@examples.com</td>
        <td>203 East 50th St., Suite 1157, New York, NY 10022, USA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<hr>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john-doe@examples.com</td>
        <td>203 East 50th St., Suite 1157, New York, NY 10022, USA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm very sorry for not replying back earlier. The negative margin approach looks promising. I played around with it and it seems like it does not require all CSS properties that are set in CodePen. It seems to only require `input { margin-right: -100vh; }` additional to the CSS mentioned in my question. Any reasons you have added the additional ones? Are there any pros and cons for either of the two approaches?

Comment: @jelhan nowrap on the first cell, is for a width wide enough to keep input usable, min-width would do too (it was to show the shrink to content). float , is to remove gap under input, vertical-align or display:block would do too. height was a left over .

Comment: adding position:relative to the problematic element solved my responsiveness problem I've been experiencing with ionic-grid